# Returning iterator from constant member function

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, c++14

In the following code why the return type of `foo::func` is `vector<int>::const_iterator` and not `vector<int>::iterator` though I am returning an object of `vector<int>::iterator`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class foo
{
private:
  vector<int> ar;
public:
  foo()
  {
    ar.resize(10);
    iota(ar.begin(), ar.end(), 1);
  }
  auto func() const
  {
    return ar.begin() + 5;
  }
};

int main()
{
  foo x;
  cout<<boolalpha<<endl;
  auto it = x.func();
  cout<<is_same<decltype(it), vector<int>::iterator>::value<<endl;
  cout<<is_same<decltype(it), vector<int>::const_iterator>::value<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output of above code is :

```
false
true
```

Instead if I redefine `foo::func()` as

```
auto func()
{
    return ar.begin() + 5;
}
```

The output will be

```
true
false
```

Why the constant member function is changing return type to constant?
And should I need to remove `const` keyword to make the return type  as `vector<int>::iterator` or is there any other way?

Comment: `ar` is an lvalue of type `const vector<int>` within `auto func() const`.

Comment: [`const_iterator begin() const;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) is invoked when access to the vector `ar` is `const`, which it is because `func() const` said it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There are two](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) `std::vector::begin` depending on whether the instance is `const` or not.

In `foo::func() const`, you are trying to access `ar` which is then viewed as a `const std::vector<int>`, and `std::vector::begin() const` returns a `const_iterator`.

When you access `ar` in `foo::func()`, it is then viewed as a `std::vector<int>`, without `const`, and `begin` will then refer to `std::vector::begin()` (without `const` again), which is not the same function.

Similarly, your own `foo` class could define two versions of `foo::func` simultaneously:

```
auto func()
{ return ar.begin() + 5; }

auto func() const
{ return ar.begin() + 5; }
```

And the constness of the instances will decide which version to call:

```
foo x;
const foo y;

x.func();    // First version, get an iterator
y.func();    // Second version, get a const_iterator
```

Answer (score 5):

A member function declared `const` affects the type of the `this` pointer. Within `func()`, `this` has type `const foo*`. As a result, all member types accessed via a `const` `this` pointer will themselves be `const`, so the implicit type of `ar` is in fact `const std::vector<int>`. Of the two [`begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) overloads for `vector`, the only viable overload is the `const` overload, which returns a `const_iterator`.

When you redefine `func()` to be non-`const`, then the type of `this` is simply `foo*`, so the type of the member `ar` is `std::vector<int>` and the overload of `begin()` returning `iterator` is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

The `iterator` points to one of its data members and so if the function is `const` then the `iterator` must be `const` too otherwise you could change the data contained in the `class` from the `iterator` returned by a `const` member function.

That's my understanding at least - I would be grateful if someone else could confirm or deny this.

Comment: It is possible to invent a container such that a const instance returns an iterator that lets one mutate the container's elements. The distinction between those two cases is *via some convention*. The Standard Library container classes follow a convention called *value semantics*, which implies seeing a container as a sequence of its elements. Under this convention, a container is considered modified if the elements are modified. Hence, StdLib containers only expose const iterators from const member functions.

Answer (score 2):

Member function `begin` is overloaded the following way

```
iterator begin() noexcept;
const_iterator begin() const noexcept;
```

Thus functions that are declared with qualifier `const` deal with constant objects. That means that data members of a constant object if they are not declared as `mutable` are also constant. In this case the second overloaded function `begin` is called for data member `ar` that returns `const_iterator`.